# How to request features in a QGIS plugin?

Tags: qgis-plugins

How does one go about requesting a feature to a certain plug-in?  The plug-in author is no longer active but he said I could request/implement the feature to someone who maintains plug-ins for QGIS.  The plug-in is 'Rectangles Ovals Digitising'.

Answer (score 1):

Here ist the project repository at github: https://github.com/vinayan/RectOvalDigitPlugin . You should raise the issue there.

Comment: For the curious: Clutch created an issue on the github repo: https://github.com/vinayan/RectOvalDigitPlugin/issues/4